# How to split header values?

Tags: http, http-headers, rfc2616

I'm parsing HTTP headers. I want to split the header values into arrays where it makes sense.

For example, `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` should return `['no-cache','no-store']`.

HTTP RFC2616 says:

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present
>   in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header
>   field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. **It MUST
>   be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
>   "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
>   message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
>   separated by a comma.** The order in which header fields with the same
>   field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation
>   of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the
>   order of these field values when a message is forwarded

But I'm not sure if the reverse is true -- is it safe to *split* on comma?

I've already found one example where this causes problems. My User-Agent string, for example, is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
```

i.e., it contains a comma after "KHTML". Obviously I don't have more than one user agent, so it doesn't make sense to split this header.

Is User-Agent string the only exception, or are there more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not safe to split headers based on commas. As an example, `Accept: foo/bar;p="A,B,C", bob/dole;x="apples,oranges"` is a valid header but if you try to split on the comma with the intention of getting a list of mime-types, you'd get invalid results.

The correct answer is that each header is specified using ABNF, most of them in various RFCs, e.g. `Accept:` is [defined in RFC7231 Section 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2).

I had this specific problem and [wrote a parser](https://github.com/ioquatix/http-accept) and [tested it on edge cases](https://github.com/ioquatix/http-accept/blob/0f4efbe6136fdbdb5fb1f028d90a9a8e51766c18/spec/http/media_types_spec.rb#L36-L43). Not only is [parsing the header non-trivial](https://github.com/ioquatix/http-accept/blob/0f4efbe6136fdbdb5fb1f028d90a9a8e51766c18/lib/http/accept/media_types.rb#L94-L120), interpreting it and giving the [correct result is also non-trivial](https://github.com/ioquatix/http-accept/blob/0f4efbe6136fdbdb5fb1f028d90a9a8e51766c18/lib/http/accept/languages.rb#L36-L76).

Some headers are more complex than others, but essentially each header has it's own grammar which should be respected for correct (and secure) processing.

Answer (score 1):

> if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]

So it's the other way around. You can only assume that `Field: value1, value2` is equivalent to `Field: value1` + `Field: value2` when the specs say that `Field` supports `#(value)`, i.e. a comma-separated list of values.

Comment: Well that's what I was trying to say with "I'm not sure if the reverse is true". Is there somewhere I can find a list of headers that support comma separation so that I can create a black or white list at least?

Comment: @Mark I've been trying to find those, but [RFC2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), [RFC7230](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) and [RFC7231](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231) aren't quite exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the specs, I've concluded the following headers support multiple (comma-separated) values:

- Accept
- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Accept-Language
- Accept-Patch
- Accept-Ranges
- Allow
- Cache-Control
- Connection
- Content-Encoding
- Content-Language
- Expect
- If-Match
- If-None-Match
- Pragma
- Proxy-Authenticate
- TE
- Trailer
- Transfer-Encoding
- Upgrade
- Vary
- Via
- Warning
- WWW-Authenticate
- X-Forwarded-For

You can use this to create a whitelist of splittable headers.

Comment: @CodeCaster I deliberately left `Set-Cookie` off actually. The example from Wikipedia shows `sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT` -- there's a comma in the middle of the date.  I'm not sure there is a way to put more than one Set-Cookie on a line, is there?

Comment: What about `Accept: foo/bar;p="A,B"`? This is valid, but splitting on the comma would not give the desired results. Better to use specific parsers based on the RFC specifications, e.g. https://github.com/ioquatix/http-accept